# Docusign API PHP TemplatesApi::updateDocument FORMAT_CONVERSION_ERROR

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to update a template document via PHP API using this: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Api/TemplatesApi.php#L4946

I get one of two errors depending on if I set the `apply_document_fields` option.

Without it set, I get `UNSPECIFIED ERROR` `Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: fileBytes`. However, if I view the request body before sending, `document_base_64` is set as expected.

With `apply_document_fields` set `'true'` (actual boolean value is not supported), I get `FORMAT_CONVERSION_ERROR` `The data could not be converted.`

Either way, it seems like the document data is not getting sent correctly, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to be sending it. Here's my code:

```
public static function updateTemplateWithDocument(string $documentId, string $templateId, $documentBody = null)
{
    $api = My_Service_Docusign::getInstance();
    $templatesApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi($api->getAuth());

    $document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
    $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode($documentBody));
    // Got an error reusing $documentId, so I'm incrementing it now
    $document->setDocumentId((string) (((int)$documentId) + 1));

    $def = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
    $def->setDocuments(array($document));

    $opts = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi\UpdateDocumentOptions();
    // Different behavior with this set vs not
    $opts->setApplyDocumentFields('true');

    $res = $tmpApi->updateDocument($api->getAccountId(), $documentId, $templateId, $def, $opts);

    return $res;
}
```

Unfortunately, DocuSign support doesn't support their API :-(

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I need to use `TemplatesApi::updateDocuments` (plural) instead, which also allows me to reuse the `documentId`.

Comment: Good job on solving your problem. Please mark your answer as the "accepted" answer for your problem. I think you may need to wait or day or two first (StackOverflow will tell you the waiting time).